# Does ASP.NET 4.5 require .NET 4.5 (or is 4.0 sufficient?)

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, version, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5

There there is various information around, for example from Microsoft about the new features of ASP.NET 4.5.

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new

However, they do not talk about .NET versions, only of ASP.NET Versions.

**Is .NET 4.5 required (on the server) for ASP.NET 4.5?** (or is 4.0 sufficient?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must install .NET 4.5 on the server if you want to run ASP.NET 4.5 applications.  ASP.NET and .NET come bundled - you cannot have one without the other.

Answer (score 0):

Some of features needs it.But you dont have to install if you are an end user

detailed information  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx